# Square root of complex numbers

Tags: equation-solving, complex

This is a pretty simple issue with Mathematica but I could not find any previous discussion on this topic. The issue arises when we have fractions as indices of complex numbers. For e.g. Let's say we try to find the square root of the complex number $(8-x +6i)$.

Now, from basic complex number algebra, we know that the real part of the  $\sqrt{(8-x +6i)}$ is aperiodic. In fact, Real part of the square root is $\pm\sqrt{0.5((8-P)+\sqrt{ {(8-P)}^2 + 6^2 })}$, which is aperiodic.

```
expr[x_] = ((8 - x) - 6 i)^(0.5)
expr1[x_] = expr[x] // Rationalize[#, 0] & // Re // 
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // FullSimplify
```

The output of the `expr1[x]` is given in this weird form: `(36 + (-8 + x)^2)^(1/4) Cos[1/2 ArcTan[8 - x, -6]]`. More importantly, this looks like a perioidic function.

This becomes an even bigger issue when the indices of the complex number is something like {1/4,1/3,7/3,etc..}.

As an example, I give a complex number raised to `19/3`.

```
expr8[x_] = (0.0133707 - 
    0.053536 I)/((0.905625 - 0.375 I) + (0. + 1.5 I) x)^(19/3)
expr9[x_] = 
 expr8[x] // Rationalize[#, 0] & // Re // 
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // FullSimplify



(46976204800000 5^(
 2/3) (19101 Cos[19/3 ArcTan[200/483 (-1 + 4 x)]] - 
   76480 Sin[19/3 ArcTan[200/483 (-1 + 4 x)]]))/(729 3^(
 1/3) (273289 + 320000 x (-1 + 2 x))^(19/6))
```

Plotting the real part,i.e. expr9[x] gives me something like this.

[image]

I think this happens because when I want to compute the real part of ${(r e^{(i\theta)})^{1/k}}$, Mathematica gives me something like $r^{\frac{1}{k}}cos(\frac{\theta}{k})$. Clear this output is periodic and can have -ve values. Is there a way to specify to Mathematica give me only the positive roots at each $x$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**The `ArcTan` part is not weird. And the real part is aperiodic.**

*I am not giving a full answer, because I don't use Mathematica. but I will answer the "aperiodic or periodic formula" part.*

A complex number can always be represented in the polar form: `R*(cosθ+isinθ)`.

Let's say `Z1 = (8-x) + 6i = R1*(cosθ+isinθ)`, where `R1 = sqrt((8-x)^2+6^2)`

Suppose your target number (the square root) is `Z2 = R2*(cosα+isinα)`.

we have `(R2*(cosα+isinα))^2 = R2^2*(cosα+isinα)^2`

According to [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), `(cosα+isinα)^2 = cos2α+isin2α`

Because `Z2` is the square root of `Z1`, now we have `R2^2*(cos2α+isin2α) = R1*(cosθ+isinθ)`

It's easy to get `R1 = R2^2`, and `θ = 2α`

So, how to solve this formula ?

`R2 = sqrt(R1) = sqrt(sqrt((8-x)^2+6^2)) = ((8-x)^2+6^2)^(1/4)`

`θ = arctan(6/(8-x))`

thus `α = θ/2 = (1/2)*arctan(6/(8-x))`

Finally, the real part of `Z2` (the square root) is:

`R2 * cosα = ((8-x)^2+6^2)^(1/4) * cos((1/2)*arctan(6/(8-x)))`

**TL;DR:**

**So, it is a result of an aperiodic function times a "looks like periodic" function (in fact, `arctan` is not periodic), therefore, it is aperiodic.**

*In fact, I think a link of De Moivre's formula is enough to explain the `arctan` part. And in that case, it would be better if I can give the link in the comments for brevity, instead of typing this long answer. But I don't have 50 reputation to do that.*